# Page numbers not functioning

Tags: php, pagination

I'm currently trying to implement pagination into my table, however, whenever i click on the pages, they do not show me the next page even though the link on the address bar clearly says page=2, page=3 etc. Im wondering if theres any mistakes that i did with my code. Thank you

```
    $totalPerPage = 20;
    $size= "50";
    $sql = ("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shoe s 
            INNER JOIN shoelace sc ON s.cod = sc.cod
            WHERE s.shoefit =?");

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$size]);

    $numberofResults = $stmt->rowCount();
        $numberOfPages = ceil($numberofResults/$totalPerPage);

        if(isset($_GET['page'])){
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }else{
            $page = 1;
        }

        $thePageFormula = ($page-1)*$totalPerPage;
        $query = ("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shoe s 
                INNER JOIN w_shoelace sc ON s.cod = sc.cod
                WHERE s.shoefit =?
                LIMIT $thePageFormula,$totalPerPage");

        $stmt2 = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt2->execute([$size]);


while($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    //echos infromation in table form
    echo "<table><tr onclick='javascript:showRow(this);'><td>" 
    . $row['shoename'] . "</td><td>"
    . utf8_encode($row['shoecolor']) . "</td><td>"
    <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['shoeimg'])."'width='50' height='30'/></td><tr>"; 
    echo "</table>";
} 



   for ($page=1; $page <= $numberOfPages ; $page++){ 

    echo "<div class='pagination'> 
            <a href='?page=" . $page . "'>" . $page . "</a>
        </div>";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this SQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shoe s 
                INNER JOIN w_shoelace sc ON s.cod = sc.cod
                WHERE s.shoefit =?
                LIMIT $thePageFormula,$totalPerPage
```

For pagination you have to always maintain the **offset** value for the SQL query which means from where it should start fetching the data from database. The above query should look something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shoe s 
                    INNER JOIN w_shoelace sc ON s.cod = sc.cod
                    WHERE s.shoefit =?
                    LIMIT *limit_to_show_per_page*, *offset*
```

If you start fetching the data from database and your limit is 10 for first page then your offset value must be 0 and if go to second page then the limit per page would be fixed that is 10 and your offset would change from 0 to 10 and so on.
Hope you get the point.

Comment: Are *limit_to_show_per_page* and  *offset* supposed to be variables that i created?

Comment: YES, you need to maintain a variable to track the offset value

Comment: So I have changed the LIMIT variables, but instead now no data is showing.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shoe s 
                    INNER JOIN w_shoelace sc ON s.cod = sc.cod
                    WHERE s.shoefit =?
                    LIMIT $totalPerPage,$thePageFormula;

or should i do something like this

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shoe s 
                    INNER JOIN w_shoelace sc ON s.cod = sc.cod
                    WHERE s.shoefit =?
                    LIMIT $totalPerPage OFFSET $thePageFormula;